# EventLog Properties related

Tags: c#, event-log

How to write C#.NET code for Log Size groupbox(in Properties window,Application eventlog,Eventviewer in WIndows XP OS) in EventViewer - Eventlog Properties.

Please provide me the code for the same.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm not getting what you're asking for. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what sukumar is asking is how can he programatically change the size of an event log in C#?

```
// Get the Event Log
this.eventLog = new EventLog();           
this.eventLog.Source = "Your.Log.Source";

// Configure the Event Log
// Set the log size
this.eventLog.MaximumKilobytes = 5120;
// Ower-write old records when log becomes full
this.eventLog.ModifyOverflowPolicy(OverflowAction.OverwriteAsNeeded, 0);

// Add the trace listner
Trace.Listeners.Add(new EventLogTraceListener(this.eventLog));
```

If you righ-click on an event log (eg the Application Log), and select properties. You will see there is a log size that you can set.

The problem is say you have a *custom* log that you are writing to. The overflow action is set to `DoNotOverwrite` (by default), if you don't change it to `OverwriteAsNeeded`, you will **throw an exception when the log becomes full**. System logs seem to have `OverwriteOlder` as a default.

Increasing the log size just gives you a bigger history...